# C++ Data type depends on switch case

Tags: c++, memory-management, switch-statement, type-conversion

I want to allocate memory. The data type of the pointer should be different. It depends on the function, which call my getMemory() function.

```
try{    
switch(auswahl){

        case 1:             R3vec < double >* ptr;          
                            ptr = new R3Tools::R3vec < double >[ N ]();             
                            break;

        case 2:             LocalFlow < double >* ptr;          
                            ptr = new FlowTools::LocalFlow < double >[ N ]();           
                            break;

        case 3:             LocalFlow < std::complex < double > >* ptr;             
                            ptr = new FlowTools::LocalFlow < std::complex < double > >[ N ]();          
                            break;

        default: //

}
}

catch( const std::bad_alloc& ){     
                    throw std::out_of_range("Array3D<T>::getMemory\n\tunable to satisfy request for memory!"); 
} 

return ptr;
```

I get the error message: **Invalid redeclaration of 'ptr'**

How can I solve the problem?

Note that this code appears in a function with prototype `inline void* getMemory(int) const;`

Comment: What does the signature of the function look like?

Comment: @D. Mogwitz  In any case the scope of ptr is the switch statement. If you are going to use it outside the switch statement then it should be declared before it.

Comment: Name them ptr1, ptr2, and ptr3. Problem solved, or, at least, this answers the directly posed question. Perhaps there's another reason why all three heap allocations must be assigned to the same variable called "ptr", but the reason is not demonstrated in this example. This specific example's answer is to rename the variables.

Comment: @ChristianHackl inline void* getMemory(int) const;

Comment: You can't solve it. Once declared a variable can't change type, you need some other method for it. Besides, since you declare the variables within the scope of the `switch` statement, that's the scope and the lifetime the variables will have, once the `switch` statement is done those variables cease to exist. It also looks like a pretty bad design, maybe you should start over from that angle instead of forcing the language to do something it's not really meant to do?

Comment: if all you want to return is memory (`void* getMemory(int) const;`), then `return malloc(sizeof(R3vec<double>));` might be what you need, Note however that the allocated memory is not initialized, but at least, it does what is says it does.

Comment: How is this unclear? With your current signature (which I don't specifically endorse), you want to return a `void *` - so you would just declare a `void *` at function scope, assign whatever address to that, then return it.

Comment: Also note that `case` blocks are not scoped by default, so if you want variables local to them, you can/need to provide enclosing `{ braces; }` as with any other scope. Not that it really helps in this specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a strongly typed language which means that you need to decide on a type for `ptr` (and the function `return` type) and then *stick to it*.

A few options to consider in your case are to use (i) a common base class and return a pointer to that, (ii) a `union` with a type descriminator, or the crude (iii) return a `void*`.

Although (i) is arguably the most "object orientated way" of doing it, actually implementing this could mean a lot of boilerplate code and a lot of typing. But worth it in the long run. Given the function's return type is `void*`, you could use option (iii) and write

`return (void*)new R3Tools::R3vec < double >[ N ]();` etc.

in each `case`. This obviates the need for the variable `ptr` *and* the `break` statements. But casting the pointer back to something meaningful (essential for the necessary subsequent `delete`) will be difficult.

What you *can't* do is redeclare `ptr` in the `switch` block. In this respect a `switch` block is little more than a `goto` with a series of labels: the scoping rules are similar.

Comment: Is your option safe enough? It looks good to return directly the pointer in every case.

Comment: It's safe so long as you don't attempt to cast the `void*` back to something that is was not to start with. That could be tricky. I still think that (i) is the best way.

Comment: in case of iii) deleting a void* will not call any destructors, and as we're dealing with classes in one of the best case scenarios this 'only' leak memory.

Comment: Yup, the OP would have to convert back to the relevant pointer somehow. (i) and (ii) are only really feasible.

Comment: I just want to get memory with the switch statement for different data types. Your solution looks good. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to `delete` the memory though. @Lanting's comment is important.

Comment: @Lanting I have a private class member for example R3vec <double>*  coordinate. If I need this values now, I call a function, which should get memory with the switch statement above. It looks like: coordinate = getMemory(); After that I want to put my values in it.

Comment: @Lanting In my destructor I delete all my pointers of the class.